# Rails Rspec factory girl issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Hello i have problem with factory girl in rspec.
I have test to check user validation:

expect(FactoryGirl.create(:user)).to be_valid

my factory look like that

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username "username_test"
    email "username_test@gmail.com"
    password "test_passwordddd"
  end
end
```

validation is that password must be more than 8 chars long.
This test fails and when i inspect FactoryGirl object it have password set to 0. Any ideas ?

Regards

Comment: Can you post your `User` model please?

Comment: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password_confirmation 

  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :password

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_length_of :password
  validates_confirmation_of :password`

Comment: Have you tried using `FactoryGirl.lint` http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Linting_Factories? I'd be interested to see its output.

Comment: `Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint
     
     FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError:
       The following factories are invalid:
            * user - (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

Comment: Dumping in everything you've described above your tests pass for me. So you've omitted something in your question. I'm assuming you mean that your password is 0 length when you inspect it? This would be because you're running `clear_password` after_save

Comment: Correct Gavin, clear password made error ! Thanks for help